# Does 'make and program device' first perform a clean?

Tags: pic, mplabx

In MPLABX v2.00, I'm always scared of introducing some bug by not remembering to first delete all old object files.  I'm inspecting the output of the build process but do not know for sure **whether everything in the `/build` (where debugging build goes) and `/dist` (where the release build goes) directories are being deleted.**

```
make -j 16 -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/.../MyProject.X.production.hex
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of "make" (in the Unix sense) is to *avoid* reprocessing files that haven't changed since the last iteration. If you don't trust this mechanism, then you should always do a "[Clean and Build Project](http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx%3abuild)".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the "Make and Program", then waiting a few minutes, and then doing it again.  You can check the timestamps of all the files in those directories, and see if any of them weren't updated.